# Cannot assign drive letter to SD card partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, sd-card

I flashed a custom firmware to an SD card for a little hand held console called Bittboy Pocket Go. After flashing it, I tried using minitool partition to expand the partition and assign a letter. It successfully expands the drive, but it does not assign the letter. It says it is successful, but there is no letter, and windows does not see the drive even though it appears in the list. If I try to assign a letter with windows management, I get an error saying the operation failed because the disk managment console view is not up to date. I even tried restarting my PC. Still nothing.

How do I go about getting this to work? Without being able to see the drive I cannot move files to it.

***UPDATE***

I just learned that windows can only use the first partition on a drive so that is probably why windows cannot read the partitioned drive. How would I make it the first one?

[image: Move Partitoin]

Thank you

Comment: Which Windows release are you using? Current Windows 10.18xx and 10.19xx supports multiple partitions on removable disks; older versions did not.

Comment: Boot e.g. an Ubuntu installation disk in "Try" mode, and use "gparted" to rearrange partitions.

Answer (score 0):

To make the partition the first one, you need to use a partition editor
(like the one you used to create it), in order to move it to the top of the disk.

As there are three partitions that stand in the way, they will have to be deleted.
If you wish to keep them, you will need to copy them elsewhere, delete,
move the partition, finally re-create the deleted partitions and reload their
contents.

However, there is no guarantee that this software is flexible enough to still
boot when the partition order was changed.
In that case, you would need to undo the move in the same way.

An alternative way without moving or assigning a drive letter,
would be to access the disk via Linux on Windows.
Linux does support multiple partitions in USB disks.
You could for example install Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store, then use Ubuntu
tools to access the disk.